# How to return multiple rows based on maximum value in one of its column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table in which there are two fields, **name** and **number** ( I am just presenting my problem premise here) and suppose I am to return the row(s) with the maximum of such **numbers**. If I use the command

```
SELECT name, MAX(number) FROM tablename;
```

However, if I have two or more such rows with the maximum **numbers**, how I am to modify the above query so as to get all the rows?

**EDIT:** I want it to return all the rows where such a maximum may be found, not just one of the rows, and it should be correctly associated with the right name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where t.number = (select max(number) from tablename);
```

Your query, by the way, only returns the maximum number.  It returns an arbitrary value for `name` that can be from any row.

If you want only one value, you should use:

```
select t.*
from tablename
order by number desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: I want it to return all the rows where such a maximum may be found, not just one of the rows, and it should be correctly associated with the right name.

Comment: @SoulRayder . . . That is what the first query does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a group by clause in order to have the max number associated with the appropriate name. Hope this works for you.

```
select
    name, max(number)
from
    yourtable
group by
    name
```

Comment: This will give the max value for every name in the table.

Comment: Isn't that what he is asking for? See the statement "it should be correctly associated with the right name" in the question edit. Thanks.

Comment: He wants all the names that have the max value. Not the max value of all the names. That's quite different.

Comment: Oh k. Then i guess @Gordon's first query should give the correct result, just need to add a "select distinct t.*" there i guess.